# google ios SDK swift fit bounds to user location and selected marker place

Tags: swift, google-maps, localization, marker, userlocation

I would like to zoom for selected place and user location using google map.

I have method for fit bounds:

```
func fitToMarker(marker: GMSMarker) {
        let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds()
        bounds.includingCoordinate(self.userMarker.position)
        bounds.includingCoordinate(marker.position)
        self.mapView.animate(with: GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds))
    }
```

and I use it after selected button in method:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work correctly"?

Comment: in general it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `- (GMSCoordinateBounds *) includingCoordinate: (CLLocationCoordinate2D) coordinate`
>
> Returns a GMSCoordinateBounds representing the current bounds extended
>   to include the passed-in coordinate.
>
> If the current bounds is invalid, the result is a valid bounds
>   containing only coordinate.

`includingCoordinate` method doesn't mutate existing `GMSCoordinateBounds`, but returns a new `GMSCoordinateBounds`. Try this

```
func fitToMarker(marker: GMSMarker) {
    var bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds()
    bounds = bounds.includingCoordinate(self.userMarker.position)
    bounds = bounds.includingCoordinate(marker.position)
    self.mapView.animate(with: GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds))
}
```